# Cannot copy SWF or MP3 file to Windows file server

Tags: windows, shared-folders

I'm trying to archive a bunch of files to a Windows file server in a corporate environment. I'm stuck on a file named history.swf, which fails to copy with an access denied error.

Testing a bit further, I found that

`echo test > \\server\share\test.txt`

works just fine, whereas

`echo test > \\server\share\test.swf`

fails with "Access is denied".

Does anyone know why this may happen or what I can do to further diagnose this issue?

Comment: These are shockwave files and not used any more. Can you convert the swf files to another format that is current and then copy the new files.  SWF files were used for phishing spam.

Comment: No, I'm trying to archive some stuff here.

Comment: Use WinZip or like to combine the files

Comment: Yep, that's the workaround. Sigh. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Windows has a Server Resource Management service (SRMSVC) which can be used to prevent certain file types from being stored on the server. In our case, there's an audio/video file filter, which includes SWF. MP3 shows the same behavior.

The server shows a corresponding event when users attempt to create/rename/copy files with forbidden file names. (SRMSVC event 8215, see http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-8215-source-SRMSVC-eventno-6855-phase-1.htm)

So the only workaround here is to zip up the folders I'm trying to archive.

Comment: I'll let the community decide whether this question is valuable for anybody or should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is reasonable. People need to archive files from time to time. SWF and similar types of files cannot be copied to servers (logical OS prevention) because they are often a source of spam.

Use WinZip or 7-Zip (top quality ZIP tools) to combine the files and archive them. Then you can copy the ZIP archives.